# Change Classpath in SBT during test

Tags: sbt, classpath

How do I add the `resourceDirectory` in Java **Classpath** while SBT runs tests?

For now I only have sbt jar.

My need is due to a dependency (spark-cassandra-connector EmbeddedCassandra) loading a resource via `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream` rather than `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource` ...

Comment: What is System Classpath?

Comment: With "System Classpath", I mean what is set either with "java -cp ..." or CLASSPATH system property (and you get with `System.getProperty("java.class.path");` as opposed to SBT fullClasspath.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new file/folder to your Java Classpth you can add the following line in your `build.sbt`:

```
(fullClasspath in Test) := (fullClasspath in Test).value ++ Seq(Attributed.blank((resourceDirectory in Test).value))
```

This will add the folder given by the `test:resourceDirectory` setting to the Classpath under the `Test` configuration.

Note:

> The fullClasspath task provides a classpath including both the dependencies and the products of a project. For the test classpath, this includes the main and test resources and compiled classes for the project as well as all dependencies for testing.

...

> fullClasspath is the concatenation of `dependencyClasspath` and `exportedProducts`

More details can be found [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Classpaths.html).

Comment: Here is what I get when, after adding what you suggest, I `System.out.println(s"classpath: ${System.getProperty("java.class.path")}")` just before trying (unsuccessfully) to access the test resource: _classpath: /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.8/libexec/sbt-launch.jar_

Comment: I am not sure the `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` gives you entirely what you need. On SBT try show `test:fullClasspath` and it will show that the resource folder is added. I actually went all the way and added a jar in the `fullClasspath` and compiled to see if it gets loaded and everything worked fine.

Comment: showing fullClasspath in Test displays everything that is configured plus defaults (test resources being part of it). This is actually where resources are looked for when you do `getClass.getClassLoader.getResource` but not when you do `ClassLoader.getSystemResource` (what happens inside the lib I'm using, as I state in my question)